# What is the cause of this error with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This MWE does not compile

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-tab} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\value}{1}; 
\tkzTabInit 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

The error is

> Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `t' or` tk' (in
> '0{tkz@cnt@cl}').

Do you have an idea of the cause of the error?

Comment: Here is a MWE: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\value}{1};
\tkzTabInit
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\value` is an elementary LaTeX macro for accessing the value of a counter, see e.g. http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_13.html.

Redefining it will certainly break something. According to the error message, LaTeX tries to access the value of the counter `tkz@cnt@cl`, by executing `\value{tkz@cnt@cl}`. Since `\value` expands to `1`, we end up with `1{tkz@cnt@cl}`, which is not a valid expression. (Note: The code in the original posting is not consistent with the error message given below it, as the code sets `\value` to one, while `\value` expands to zero in the error message.)

Rename the variable `\value` to something else.

But even then you may expect further problems, as the macro `\tkzTabInit` expects two mandatory arguments.